# GCP Cloud Trace for GCE

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have GCE instances and provide our own Web APIs on the VMs. I really want to use GCP Cloud Trace to check the latency. Can I use it on GCE? Some say that it works on GAE. As far as I've read docs, it does not seem that I can use it.